# Generate Rmakrdown formula inside R codechunk and use it out-of chunk later

Tags: dynamic, r-markdown, equation

I am trying to solve the following:
In RMarkdown, I want to dynamically create a formula within an R chunk but then use it outside of that chunk, for instance:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
alpha<-0.25
myformula<-"$$ x_{`r alpha`}$$"
```

This should display my formula `r myformula`.
````

This first trial returns an error due to the grave accents. However, doing this directly results in

```
This should display my formula $$x_{`r alpha`}$$.
```

Can anyone advice on this? I am sort of relying on generating the formula in the chunk in order to be able to use ifelse statements.

Thanks in advance